# Is there a difference between iterating a Map directly and via an iterator returned by entries()?

Tags: javascript, es6-map

If I have a `Map` in JavaScript, e.g

```js
const myMap = new Map()
myMap.set(0, 'zero')
myMap.set(1, 'one')
```

Then both of these two seem to be valid to iterate through the key-value pairs
(and many other options which I am currently not interested in):

```js
// with .entries()
for (const [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  //
}
// without
for (const [key, value] of myMap) {
  //
}
```

Is there any edge case where they do not do the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any edge case where they do not do the same?

No. The iterator object you get from `entries` is exactly the same one provided by the map itself. In fact, `someMap[Symbol.iterator]` (the function called when you ask an object for its iterator) is literally the exact same function as `someMap.entries`:

```js
const someMap = new Map();
console.log(someMap[Symbol.iterator] === someMap.entries);
```

In the spec:

- [`Map.prototype.entries`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map.prototype.entries)
- [`Map.prototype[@@iterator]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map.prototype-@@iterator) (`@@iterator` is `Symbol.iterator`) — which literally just points to `entries`

Answer (score 3):

Both do exactly the same by default.

When [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is used with a value as `for (const item of collection)` then the [well-known symbol `@@iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) is used to find what the values would be.

For `Map` objects, [`@@iterator` will return `.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator). It's exactly like calling the method because it *is*:

```js
const map = new Map();

console.log(map[Symbol.iterator] === map.entries);
```

Therefore, both loops will do the same.

**Small caveat**: that is *by default*. If the `@@iterator` symbol is overriden, then there can be different results:

```js
const myMap = new Map()
myMap.set(0, 'zero')
myMap.set(1, 'one')

myMap[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  const entries = this.entries();
  for (const [key, value] of entries)
    yield [key, value.toUpperCase()]; //transform the value
}

// with .entries()
for (const [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log("with .entries()", key, value)
}
// without
for (const [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log("without", key, value)
}
```

However, that is exceptionally unusual to happen. And if it *does* then it is likely that whoever supplied the map might actually *want* a different iteration logic.